# How do I switch back to GDM and have it launch at boot?

Tags: gdm, login-screen, lightdm

So I got rid of Lightdm but how do I get GDM to launch at default.  It hangs on "checking battery state" this is in virtual box if that matters.  I want GDM login to load by default instead of me starting it manually.

Comment: nvm, did some more work and learned how to use rc.local.  Added "gdm &" after do start and now it boots up really really quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Congrats on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to reconfigure GDM.

To do that, switch to a tty. <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+1</kbd>

Login as your user, then run the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Select `GDM` instead of `lightdm`, then you can do a reboot (`sudo reboot` in the ttyy) and you're good to go.

Comment: I know I can open a terminal in gdm and then run unity, but how do I get unity to run on startup within gdm?